# Sums of permutations of vectors

Tags: math, permutations, fastest-code

I am looking for a more efficient way of computing the following.

Let `A` and `B` be two vectors of non-negative integers of length `a` and `b`.
Let `A0` and `B0` be the padded versions of `A` and `B`, so that we pad the vectors by 0, until their lengths are `a+b`.

We now want to compute `sort(A0 + pB0)` where `pB0` ranges over all *distinct* permutations of `B0`, and keep track of how many times a result is obtained.

For example, `A={2,1,1}`, `B={3,1}` gives `A0={2,1,1,0,0}`, `B0={3,1,0,0,0}`,
and the expected output is

```
{{5,2,1},2}
{{5,1,1,1},2}
{{4,3,1},2}
{{3,3,1,1},2}
{{4,2,2},2}
{{4,2,1,1},4}
{{3,2,2,1},4}
{{3,2,1,1,1},2}
```

For example, {5,2,1} is obtained from the two cases
{2,1,1,0,0}+{3,1,0,0,0} and {2,1,1,0,0}+{3,0,1,0,0}.

The Mathematica code I use for generating this is given as follows:
myFunction[A_, B_] := Module[{n, A0, B0},
n = Length[A] + Length[B];
A0 = PadRight[A, n];
B0 = PadRight[B, n];
Tally@Table[Sort[DeleteCases[A0 + pB0, 0], Greater],
{pB0, Permutations@B0}]
];
Timing[
Table[
myFunction[A, B]
, {A, IntegerPartitions[8]}
, {B, IntegerPartitions[8]}]
]

I am looking for a solution which does this quickly, for say all integer partitions A, B of some maximal size n. A recursive solution with memoization would be ok (and perhaps preferred if this leads to greater speed).

The motivation for this question has to do with multiplication of monomial symmetric functions.

Comment: Are you looking for speed optimization or code length optimization?

Comment: Speed optimization - i did not see the tag speed in the list of tags...

Comment: [tag:fastest-code], or [tag:fastest-algorithm]

Comment: You'll have to choose either [`fastest-code`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/fastest-code/info) or [`fastest-algorithm`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/fastest-algorithm/info). These tags are in conflict with each other.

Comment: @Arnauld ok, fastest algorithm it is then.

Comment: If you can produce examples of different difficulty and make it fastest-code you will get the highest quality answers in my experience. This is assuming you want to solve it in practice.

Comment: I'm not sure if I misunderstood the question. But... For O(n) input `A = {n+1, 2n+2, 3n+3, ..., (n+1)n}`, `B={1, 2, 3, ..., n}`; The program should generate O(n\*n!) outputs. So the fastest algorithm could not be faster than O(n\*n!). But an O(n\*n!) algorithm could be trivial.

Comment: @ths perhaps, but I am looking for some improvements which take advantage of cases when many entries are equal, or a recursive method, where smaller cases are already assumed to be known. Say you want to compute this for all A and B where A and B ranges over all integer partitions if size less than 10.

Comment: @Per But the trivial algorithm is the (asymptotically) fastest algorithm then.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate ok, then perhaps fasted code is the more appropriate tag. One should be able to make significant gains by doing a recursive approach, assuming that one has already computed the results for vectors with fewer entries...

Comment: Is this meant to be asking for programming help, or posing a challenge? I think if you don't have a sense of strong solutions to the problem, it's likely to turn out to not be a well-crafted challenge.

Comment: Why isn't `{0,0,1,1,2}+{0,0,0,1,3}` counted?

Comment: How are answers going to be scored?  You can't just add [tag:fastest-code] to a challenge and be done with it, you need to actually explain how scoring works.